# Conditions set inside method to find prime number not working

Tags: java

i set an if to check if the numbers being sent we're divisible by 3 or 7 or so on..
but it doesn't seem to do that.

i tried changing how it worked which is why it looks like this now but it still doesn't work.

```
public void primeNumbers() {
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of prime numbers you'd like: ");

        int numberOfPrimes = reader.nextInt();

        int numbersFound = 0;
        int foundCount = 0;

        while(foundCount < numberOfPrimes)  {
            if (numbersFound < 2) {
                numbersFound++;
            }
            else if(numbersFound % 3 == 0 || numbersFound % 5 == 0 || numbersFound % 7 == 0 || numbersFound % 11 == 0 || numbersFound == 2) {
                System.out.print(numbersFound +" ");
                foundCount++;
                numbersFound++;
            }
            else {
                numbersFound++;
            }

        }
    }
```

no errors, it's just the numbers coming out aren't prime.

Comment: you print numbers that are dividable by 3. those are not prime, obv.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it wasn't working.
I just forgot to set a condition that said that if the number is divisible by 2, then skip. 
And instead of making all the numbers that are divisible by 3 7 5 and 11 be printed 
i make them not be printed
im pretty sure 
Sorry lol